# Limit physical memory per process

Tags: c++, linux, memory, process, linux-kernel

I am writing an algorithm to perform some external memory computations, i.e. where your input data does not fit into main memory and you have to consider the I/O complexity.

Since for my tests I do not always want to use *real inputs* I want to limit the amount of memory available to my process. What I have found is, that I can set the `mem` kernel parameter to limit the physically used memory of all processes (is that correct?)

Is there a way to do the same, but with a *per process limit*. I have seen `ulimit`, but it only limits the **virtual** memory per process. Any ideas (maybe I can even set it programmatically from within my C++ code)?

Comment: Are you relying on virtual memory and the linux's paging for loading the relevant data into memory, or do you plan to load the data manually yourself into buffers?

Comment: I use virtual memory + linux's paging (plus a library called stxxl for some external memory data structures, but I can already control the memory usage of those)

Comment: Added linux-kernel tag because you probably need to talk with the kernel directly for this, and the kernel guys are the most likely to know about it.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44985/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try with 'cgroups'.
To use them type the following commands, as root.

```
# mkdir /dev/cgroups
# mount -t cgroup -omemory memory /dev/cgroups
# mkdir /dev/cgroups/test
# echo 10000000 > /dev/cgroups/test/memory.limit_in_bytes
# echo 12000000 > /dev/cgroups/test/memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes
# echo <PID> > /dev/cgroups/test/tasks
```

Where  is the PID of the process you want to add to the cgroup. Note that the limit applies to the sum of all the processes assigned to this cgroup.

From this moment on, the processes are limited to 10MB of physical memory and 12MB of pysical+swap.

There are other tunable parameters in that directory, but the exact list will depend on the kernel version you are using.

You can even make hierarchies of limits, just creating subdirectories.

The cgroup is inherited when you fork/exec, so if you add the shell from where your program is launched to a cgroup it will be assigned automatically.

Note that you can mount the cgroups in any directory you want, not just /dev/cgroups.

Comment: I should be able to verify that limitations are satisfied using `/proc/<pid>/status` and the `VmHWM` entry, right?

Comment: I'm not sure this is so straightforward. Comparing the /proc/<pid>/status with the cgroups/*/memory.usage_in_bytes they are somewhat different. Maybe related to shared memory or virtual vs. physical memory... I think that cgroups limit only the new memory requested by the process, but the shared memory that existed before the process is added to the cgroup is not accounted for. See the docs [here](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt).

Comment: Accepting this answer: cgroups worked for me. Is `-omemory` a typo (no space)? Anyways I found it more comfortable to set up the cgconfig accordingly and start my process directly in a cgroup (cgexec), like here for example http://jlebar.com/2011/6/15/Limiting_the_amount_of_RAM_a_program_can_use.html

Comment: No typo, actually, the space is optional, although it would look nicer with it.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the setrlimti with the RLIMIT_AS parameter to set the limit of virtual memory (this is what ulimit does) and then have the process use mlockall(MCL_CURRENT|MCL_FUTURE) to force the kernel to fault in and lock into physical RAM all the process pages, so that amount virtual == amount physical memory for this process

Comment: `mlockall` is really problematic. Except from the fact that in some cases you really want to limit physical memory AND to enjoy swap (e.g., desktop application), some programming languages (e.g., golang or java) allocates a huge amount of virtual space with mmap+PROTO_ANON, so you can't use them. And even if you use C++, you won't be able to use things like asan.

Comment: (just notice I actually know the guy who gave the answer, small world...)

Answer (score 4):

I can't provide a direct answer but pertaining to doing such stuff, I usually write my own memory management system so that I can have full control of the memory area and how much I allocate. This is usually appliacble when you're writing for microcontrollers as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for the simple approach of just keeping track of your own memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

have you considered trying your code in some kind of virtual environment? A virtual machine might be too much for your needs, but something like [User-Mode Linux](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/) could be a good fit. This runs a linux kernel as a single process inside your regular operating system. Then you can provide a separate `mem=` kernel setting, as well as a separate swap space to make controlled experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel `mem=` boot parameter limits how much memory in total OS will use.

This is almost never what user wants.

For physical memory, there is RSS rlimit aka `RLIMIT_AS`.

Comment: The doc says about RLIMIT_RSS "This limit only has effect in Linux 2.4.x, x < 30"...

Comment: Ugh, actually per process rlimit for physical memory is called "memory cgroup", otherwise more or less nothing is guaranteed.

http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/cgroups/memory.txt;h=6f3c598971fc3ef05d2ebfb0e6e8879b3047d839;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have indicated already, setrlimit is the most probable solution, it controls the limits of all configurable aspects of a process environment. Use this command to see these individual settings on your shell process:

```
ulimit -a
```

The ones most pertinent to your scenario in the resulting output are as follows:

```
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Checkout the manual page for setrlimit ("man setrlimit"), it can be invoked programmatically from your C/C++ code. I have used it to good effect in the past for controlling stack size limits. (btw, there is no dedicated man page for ulimit, it's actually an embedded bash command, so it's in the bash man page.)